# In vscode when working on HTML file, is there a way to color the idents between the opening and closing tags?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, indentation

I have color bracket and it works great in js files where you can clearly see the nesting of functions etc.
I want that same thing but in the HTML file so the ident would be colored.

So now I'm actively in the ul indent and I want it to be colored:
[image]

Is it possible to change in the setting or a special extension? tried Googling but didn't see something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [rainbow tags extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=voldemortensen.rainbow-tags). To install it, just simply do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and paste `ext install voldemortensen.rainbow-tags` inside the box.